# React route is not working | React Router using React-router-dom

Tags: react-router, routes, react-router-dom

````
   **app.jsx is the main file handling all routes.** 

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
            <Route path="/entry-rules" component={EntryRules} />
            <Route path="/entry-form" component={EntryForm} />
            <Route path="/payment" component={Payment} />
            <Route component={Error404} />
          </Switch>
```        
 **Home route is working fine when I click others component is not working.**
 **I have used react-router-dom version 5.2.0**
```        
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/" className="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/entry-rules" className="nav-link">
                      Entry Rules
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/entry-form" className="nav-link">
                      Entry Form
                    </Link>
                  </li>
```
````

**Home route is working fine when I click others component is not working.**
**app.jsx is the main file handling all routes.**
**I have used react-router-dom version 5.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! I see you are using exact for the Home route but not for others. React Router Dom needs to be told that the path is exact, so you should do something like this:

```
       <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
            <Route path="/entry-rules" exact  component={EntryRules} />
            <Route path="/entry-rorm" exact  component={EntryForm} />
            <Route path="/payment" exact  component={Payment} />
            <Route component={Error404} path="*" />
       </Switch>
```

Notice how has '*' and no exact props. Since we want to Error404 component if RRD can't find anything from above.

Once again welcome to SO, try to structure your question nicely and upvote answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in one of the `Route`. `path` should be `"/entry-form"`

```
<Route path="/entry-rorm" component={EntryForm} />
<Link to="/entry-form" className="nav-link">
```

For other routes it should be working with your code. If not, try moving Home page route below all routes inside `<Switch>` component